# I'm Trying to create an alarm clock but it gives back this - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.weekday() == 5:
        if now.hour() == 10 and now.minute() == 30:
            webbrowser.open(url)
    elif now.hour() == 7 and now.minute == 0:
        webbrowser.open(url)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `now.minute` and `now.hour` are not functions remove the brackets on those calls.

Comment: didn't work but still thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`hour` and `minute` are not methods, you do not need to call them.

```
if now.weekday() == 5:
    if now.hour == 10 and now.minute == 30:
        webbrowser.open(url)
elif now.hour == 7 and now.minute == 0:
    webbrowser.open(url)
```