# Why is datetime.minute an attribute while datetime.weekday() is a function?

Tags: python

I added a comment to the question here: [I'm Trying to create an alarm clock but it gives back this - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617276/im-trying-to-create-an-alarm-clock-but-it-gives-back-this-typeerror-int-ob) asking why the following doesn't work:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.weekday() == 5:
        if now.hour() == 10 and now.minute() == 30:
            webbrowser.open(url)
    elif now.hour() == 7 and now.minute == 0:
        webbrowser.open(url)
    time.sleep(1)
```

and when I quickly checked the problem I just tested to see if `now.weekday()` was a function.  I then proceeded to comment saying that the OP had missed brackets on `now.minute` and thus the function wasn't being called by assuming that if `now.weekday()` was a function then `now.hour` and `now.minute` were too.

This isn't the case and while `now.weekday()` is a function, `now.hour` and `now.minute` are actually attributes.

Why is this the case?  Why are they not all functions/all attributes rather than a mixture of the two?

Comment: Because setting the minute makes sense but setting the weekday does not.

Comment: As in it is possible to change the minutes and it will update the datetime object respectively? While leaving the day etc. untouched, as obviously in that case it would not make sense to change the weekday.

Comment: Because a weekday is a *derived value*, based on other attributes. It only needs to be calculated if you actually are going to use it.

Comment: @NickA: you can with the `.replace()` method, creating a new instance. You can't set the weekday with that either.

Comment: Read the [first sentence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects): "A datetime object is a single object containing all the information from a date object and a time object" and while `date.weekday()` is a method, `time.minute` is an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `datetime` object is created from the `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`, `microsecond` and `tzinfo` values, not a weekday. You can't create such an object from raw numbers with a weekday specified.

As such, the input numbers for a `datetime` object are attributes.

But the *weekday* is a *derived* value, calculated from the core information, and by making `weekday` a method you explicitly ask for it to be computed.